# Change Nick Name of Email while sending the email from netsuite script 2.0

Tags: netsuite

Suppose we have the code
 email.send({
                author: 17874,
                recipients: "sam172@gmail.com",
                subject: "mail from netsuite",
                body: "test body email order id: " + newOrder
        });
Can we modify the sender name only not the email.

I have to implement like if we have the email "test@gmail.com" and nick name as "Test". While sending the email it will show like from Test in recevire side. Can we change the name from test to test123.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible as far as I know. You really have two options to modify the name of the sender only:

- Either change the name of the user (the one you set in the `options.author` field).
- Or have the correct name from the beginning and then modify the reploy-to instead by setting the `options.replyTo`

This isn't exactly what you want but I think it's the only workaround.